# Error when trying to run application with SDK metamask

Tags: react-native, blockchain, web3js, metamask

I ran the metamask documentation on a new project to test and it worked, after I tried to apply it to the project I need, I get the following error.

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 24s
    817 actionable tasks: 25 executed, 792 up-to-date
    info Connecting to the development server...
    info Starting the app on "emulator-5554"...
    Starting: Intent { cmp=com.####/.MainActivity }
     BUNDLE  ./index.js 
    
    error: shim.js: /home/gabriel/teste-metamesk/shim.js: Property left of AssignmentExpression expected node to be of a type ["LVal"] but instead got "StringLiteral"
```

I tried to create a new project but without success, I get the same error